# Installing an older version of cli tox

Tags: python, tox

I cannot use the newest version of tox, this is because it automatically installs python3.12, which causes other problems for me, so I must use python3.11

---

## Brew

trying to install an older version via `brew` does not work

```
% brew install tox@4.11.3
Warning: No available formula with the name "tox@4.11.3".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for tox@4.11.3.
```

---

## Tox Installation Instructions

[The tox installation instructions do not work for me](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/installation.html)

if I install using pip (`% python3 -m pip install --user tox==4.11.3`), then there is no cli tox

```
% tox -e qa                         
zsh: command not found: tox
```

---

It appears that I also can't install pipx-in-pipx, running `python -m pip install pipx-in-pipx --user` gives

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pipx-in-pipx
  Running setup.py clean for pipx-in-pipx
Failed to build pipx-in-pipx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pipx-in-pipx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using the pip installed tox and adding

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/samgermain/Library/Python/3.9/bin"`

to the end of my `~/.zprofile`

- you may need to add it to `~/.bash_profile` depending on what your shell is